# Does Emacs has word and line completion (like Vim's insert mode completion)?

Tags: emacs, autocomplete

Vim completes words and lines with `CTRL-X P` and `CTRL-L.` There's a Emacs plugin called Company mode but this plugin interfere and cause conflicts with lots of things within Emacs (with global linum and yasnippets). I know that I can complete words with CTRL-/ in Emacs. But it is possible to take previously written lines to complete code?

Comment: I think that's more of superuser question

Comment: @notnoop <- Is this a bot? because I think my question is about programming

Comment: the question is regarding shortcuts for the emacs general purpose editor.  That's a superuser question.  I understand you commonly want such functionality while coding though.  If the question is about writing an emacs extension, or handling code completion (with yasnippets), then I think it's programming related.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for [hippie-expand](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HippieExpand)? From that web page (as of this writing, anyway):

> HippieExpand looks at the word before
>   point and tries to expand it in
>   various ways including expanding from
>   a fixed list (like `expand-abbrev`),
>   expanding from matching text found in
>   a buffer (like `dabbrev-expand`) or
>   expanding in ways defined by your own
>   functions. Which of these it tries and
>   in what order is controlled by a
>   configurable list of functions.

For a comprehensive list of completion options visit the [emacs wiki page on completion](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CategoryCompletion).

Comment: To get the behaviour similar to vim's `Ctrl-X Ctrl-L`, you need to add `try-expand-line-all-buffers` to `hippie-expand-try-functions-list`. This will expand by lines from all buffers instead of just current buffer.

Answer (score 3):

There are a gazillion ways to do completion in Emacs. Some are mode specific, some inline, some configurable and what not. [Here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CategoryCompletion) is a list of modes that might help you.

Answer (score 3):

Use numberic argument to complete by line, say `M-5 M-/` will complete by line, while `M-/` alone still complete the normal way.

`hippe-expend` function has a very useful feature which is :

`With a positive numeric argument, jumps directly to the ARG next function in this list.  With a negative argument or just C-u, undoes the expansion.`

Customize the expansion functions in `hippie-expand-try-functions-list` and put the function `try-expand-line` as 5th list element, then you could use M-5 M-/ to complete by line.

This tip is very handy and useful and I highly recommend it.

Comment: FYI `try-expand-line` is the default 5th element of `hippie-expand-try-functions-list`.

Answer (score 1):

Also worth noting: if your window manager does not steal Alt-tab, emacs will auto-complete with Alt-tab (I set up my window manager to user the "windows key" instead of alt for this very reason).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `evil`, this is the most vim-like solution I use:

```
  (defun my-expand-lines ()
    (interactive)
    (let ((hippie-expand-try-functions-list
           '(try-expand-line-all-buffers)))
      (call-interactively 'hippie-expand)))

  (define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "C-x C-l") 'my-expand-lines)
```

This way you can use our old friend `C-x C-l` in insert mode for whole line all buffers completion.

Thanks @ymln for the suggestion of using `try-expand-line-all-buffers`.