# Full-line completion in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

How can I get full-line completion in Emacs, similar to Vim's `CTRL-x l`?

For example, in Vim, if I type:

```
from d<CTRL-X>-l
```

I will get a popup like this:

[image: vim line completion popup]

Which shows all the lines matching that prefix in open buffers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't give a list to choose from (try tuning `autocomplete` for that) but otherwise gives the "feeling".

```
(defun my-expand-lines ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((hippie-expand-try-functions-list
         '(try-expand-line)))
    (call-interactively 'hippie-expand)))

(define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "C-x C-l") 'my-expand-lines)
```

Comment: Awesome! Now, is it possible to use that with a popup list?

Comment: @DavidWolever: http://cx4a.org/software/auto-complete/ is one way to get popups but AC is a beast of a library. I wouldn't know about using it.

Answer (score 1):

hippie-expand does that, you just have to configure it as described on the last answer here: [Does Emacs has word and line completion (like Vim's insert mode completion)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096186/does-emacs-has-word-and-line-completion-like-vims-insert-mode-completion)

Comment: Ah… where does it mention how to expand lines? I've poked around, but don't see anything obvious :\

Comment: Basically, you have to add the function try-expand-line to hippie-expand-try-functions-list (as in the answer you accepted). But I've never used a popup for this one either...

Answer (score 1):

Emacs comes with `multi-occur` if you are comfortable navigating the list as a buffer.

Otherwise you should get to know `helm`.  See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/14731718/903943

Answer (score 1):

It takes some doing, but you can combine company completion and hippie-expand to give you a popup menu of lines from the current buffer.

First, you need to define a function to call try-expand-line (modified to return the expansion instead of calling he-expand and returning t) from hippie-exp.el and collect all the expansions:

```
(defun get-hippie-expand-lines ()
  (let (completions-list candidate)
    (setq candidate (my-try-expand-line nil))
    (if candidate
        (progn
          (push candidate completions-list)
          (while (progn
                   (setq candidate (my-try-expand-line t))
                   (if candidate
                       (push candidate completions-list)
                     nil))))
      nil)
    completions-list))
```

Then, you can write a small company backend to give you the completion candidates through a company popup.

```
(defun company-hippie-line (command &optional arg &rest ignored)
  (interactive (list 'interactive))
  (cl-case command
    (interactive (company-begin-backend 'company-hippie-line))
    (prefix (and (not (looking-at "[:word:]"))
                 (let (p1 p2)
                  (save-excursion
                    (end-of-line)
                    (setq p2 (point))
                    (back-to-indentation)
                    (setq p1 (point)))
                  (buffer-substring-no-properties p1 p2))))
    (candidates (get-hippie-expand-lines))))
;; Uncomment if you want to get line completion popups whenever found
;; (add-to-list 'company-backends 'company-hippie-line)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x l") 'company-hippie-line)
```

See further discussion at [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/7fx7qj/keeping_company_with_hippies_another_look_at/).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18224331)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, added the essential parts of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

**[Icicles](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles)** command [`icicle-occur`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Search_Commands%2c_Overview#Introduction) does what you ask.  It lets you find and navigate among search-pattern matches across multiple files or buffers, updating the set of search hits incrementally as you change the pattern to search for.  You can progressively refine the search by applying additional patterns.  You can either access hits directly, individually, or cycle among them in various cycle orders.

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/redguardtoo/eacl - Emacs auto complete line(s)

The difference between eacl and other solutions:

- it gets more candidate by grepping files in current project (project root is automatically detected if you use git/svn/mercurial)
- it can complete multi line statement by grepping