# spacemacs evil-mode: ctrl-x-p and ctrl-x-l equivilents

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, spacemacs, evil-mode

In standard `vim`, `control` + `x`-`p` triggers word completion and `control` + `x`-`l` triggers line completion. I've transitioned towards using `spacemacs` with `evil-mode` as my main editor for application development. Does `evil-mode` support some way of replicating these gestures?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Emacs has word and line completion (like Vim's insert mode completion)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096186/does-emacs-has-word-and-line-completion-like-vims-insert-mode-completion)